# Getting "undefined" trying to create a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, chart.js

So what I want to do, is filter through an array use forEach() and for each session check the dayOfWeek it is on (Monday, Tuesday, ... ). If it is a certain day, it will multiple the price and the duration of the session to come up with an income for that day and add it to the 'mondayIncome', 'tuesdayIncome', ... and so on. I want to later use this information to create a chart. When I console.log() the function, it returns undefined, why is that? Also, would this process be easier if I had a state?

I have other files such as AddSession.js and Chart.js but I decided to make the function in my Dashboard where the chart resides, is that okay?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Income from './Income'
import Chart from './Chart'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


class Dashboard extends Component {

  dayOfWeek = () => {
    const {sessionList} = this.props;
    let sundayIncome = 0;
    let mondayIncome = 0;
    let tuesdayIncome = 0;
    let wednesdayIncome = 0;
    let thursdayIncome = 0;
    let fridayIncome = 0;
    let saturdayIncome = 0;

    sessionList.forEach(session => {
        if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Sunday') {
            sundayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
            return sundayIncome
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Monday') {
            mondayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
            return mondayIncome
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Tuesday') {
            tuesdayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
            return tuesdayIncome
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Wednesday') {
            wednesdayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
            return wednesdayIncome
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Thursday') {
            thursdayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
            return thursdayIncome
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Friday') {
            fridayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
            return fridayIncome
        }
        else {
            saturdayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
            return saturdayIncome
        }
    })
}
  render() {
    console.log(this.dayOfWeek())
    return (
      <div className="container mt-5">

        <Chart/>
        <Income/>
        <hr/>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
      sessionList : state.sessions.sessionList
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard)
```

Comment: you dont' return a value from `dayOfWeek` function

Comment: also having a `return` in `sessionList.forEach(session => {` makes no sense, since the returned value is lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how your data structure is, but hopefully the below will give an idea of how to do this. I have also mocked this function in a `codeSandBox` for you so you can see it displaying the correct data. I have not rounded the numbers (Will leave you to format it how you like).

The link to the `codeSandBox` is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/8xon4yxo58

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  dayOfWeek = () => {
    const { sessionList } = this.props;

    let sundayIncome = 0;
    let mondayIncome = 0;
    let tuesdayIncome = 0;
    let wednesdayIncome = 0;
    let thursdayIncome = 0;
    let fridayIncome = 0;
    let saturdayIncome = 0;

    sessionList.forEach(session => {
      if (session.dayOfWeek === "Sunday") {
        sundayIncome += session.price * session.duration;
      } else if (session.dayOfWeek === "Monday") {
        mondayIncome += session.price * session.duration;
      } else if (session.dayOfWeek === "Tuesday") {
        tuesdayIncome += session.price * session.duration;
      } else if (session.dayOfWeek === "Wednesday") {
        wednesdayIncome += session.price * session.duration;
      } else if (session.dayOfWeek === "Thursday") {
        thursdayIncome += session.price * session.duration;
      } else if (session.dayOfWeek === "Friday") {
        fridayIncome += session.price * session.duration;
      } else {
        saturdayIncome += session.price * session.duration;
      }
    });

    return [
      mondayIncome,
      tuesdayIncome,
      wednesdayIncome,
      thursdayIncome,
      fridayIncome,
      saturdayIncome,
      sundayIncome
    ];
  };

  render() {
    const sessionData = this.dayOfWeek();

    return (
      <div className="container mt-5">
        <p>
          {`Monday: ${sessionData[0]}`} <br />
          {`Tuesday: ${sessionData[1]}`} <br />
          {`Wednesday: ${sessionData[2]}`} <br />
          {`Thursday: ${sessionData[3]}`} <br />
          {`Friday: ${sessionData[4]}`} <br />
          {`Saturday: ${sessionData[5]}`} <br />
          {`Sunday: ${sessionData[6]}`} <br />
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const sessionList = [
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Sunday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 40
  },
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Tuesday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 2
  },
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Friday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 1
  },
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Sunday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 6
  },
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Monday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 7
  },
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Wednesday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 40
  },
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Sunday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 3
  },
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Sunday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 9
  },
  {
    dayOfWeek: "Thursday",
    price: 4.99,
    duration: 12
  }
];
```

The above produces this output

```
Monday: 34.93 
Tuesday: 9.98 
Wednesday: 199.60000000000002 
Thursday: 59.88 
Friday: 4.99 
Saturday: 0 
Sunday: 289.42
```

Hope I have understood your question correctly and the above is helpful.

Comment: Got it! Thank you :) I didn't realize forEach doesn't return a value. This helped alot!

Answer (score 1):

[**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) don't return anything ( it's return value is `undefined` ), you need to store value in variable and return at end of function.

```
    dayOfWeek = () => {
    const {sessionList} = this.props;
    let sundayIncome = 0;
    let mondayIncome = 0;
    let tuesdayIncome = 0;
    let wednesdayIncome = 0;
    let thursdayIncome = 0;
    let fridayIncome = 0;
    let saturdayIncome = 0;

    sessionList.forEach(session => {
        if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Sunday') {
            sundayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Monday') {
            mondayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Tuesday') {
            tuesdayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Wednesday') {
            wednesdayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Thursday') {
            thursdayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
        }
        else if (session.dayOfWeek === 'Friday') {
            fridayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
        }
        else {
            saturdayIncome += (session.price * session.duration) 
        }
    })
 return {sundayIncome ,mondayIncome,tuesdayIncome,wednesdayIncome,thursdayIncome,fridayIncome,saturdayIncome}
}
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but variables are already defined outside of forEach.

Comment: I am not the down voter, but you answer it isn't a solution to the problem as it calculate the total income and not the income per day

Comment: @AZ_ yes but as OP used forEach you wont be able to know which one to return. as `forEach` doesn't return values

Comment: @h1b9b yeah that's a valid point changed it to return all the values instead of one

Comment: @CodeManiac I agree return just dont make any sense inside forEach but the issue with the code is that OP is not returning anything at all.

Comment: @AZ_ `forEach don't return anything ( it's return value is undefined ), you need to store value in variable and return at end of function` i guess this tells the same thing mate :)

Comment: @CodeManiac I do understand that, but where the forEach is returned ? if it was like *return sessionList.forEach(session => {* then the comment that forEach does not return anything would be a reason for the issue. but as I said OP is not returning undefined but he is not returning anything at all.

Comment: @AZ_ if you don't return anything from function it will implicitly return `undefined` so returning undefined and not returning anything is same thing

Comment: But why use a forEach if you want to return a result and not reduce?

Comment: @h1b9b yes you can, and you lot other ways to do the same, OP selected so explaination i just modified the existing code to show as an example.

Answer (score 1):

You should return the value and use `reduce` instead of `forEach`.

It would look like:

```js
...
return sessionList.reduce(
  (income, session) => {
    income[session.dayOfWeek] += (session.price * session.duration);
    return income;
  },
  { Monday: 0, Thueday: 0, Wednesday: 0, Thursday: 0, Friday:0, Saturday: 0, Sunday: 0 }
);
...
```

Cf [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for details

As of where to create this (use a state or not) it a more architectural problem that depend on where and how you intend to use this information.

Comment: Your code has some issues mate , `income[session.dayOfWeek] += (session.price * session.duration);` will result in `NaN` as you have `[]` as accumulator, you should not use array when you want index to be anything else than number you should use `Map` or `Object`